# Does "bloviate" have a positive alternative?

Tags: word-request, verbs, phrase-request, synonyms

In Czech we use the verb "vykládat" when someone "talks about something for a longer time with passion / in detail" or vyprávět for "telling a story with passion". "Bloviate" seems to have a similar but negative meaning. Are there some English alternatives for these words / verbs with similar meaning?

Comment: The word ***bloviate*** has very little currency, so I'd avoid it in favour of more familiar alternatives such as ***speechify, pontificate, hold forth [at length],...***

Answer (score 4):

The word “expound” would be appropriate for conveying the idea that someone is speaking in great detail:

> ***expound***
>
> present and explain (a theory or idea) in detail.

Comment: Thanks - is it synonymous with "dive into a topic"? Like, could I say "*Odom continued to dive in depth on his experience as a Black actor*" instead of "*Odom continued to expound on his experience as a Black actor*" ([example source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expound))

Comment: Yes it could be used that way; it sounds a lot better actually, “dive in depth on” doesn’t sound too natural to me.

Comment: Expatiate would also work although rarer than expound.